# org-archive-location ignore heading cookie

Tags: org-mode

I have an org file that looks something like this:

```
* Tasks
** TODO A test task
* 2019
** 2019-12 December
*** 2019-12-10 Tuesday
**** Day planning
***** Tasks for today [0/1]
****** TODO Another testing task
```

I am trying to create a function which can "archive" the task under "Tasks" into the "Tasks for today". Here's what I have so far:

```
(defun archive-task-today ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-archive-location (concat "%s::datetree/** Tasks for today")))
    (org-archive-subtree)))
```

I think this is pretty close, except that it doesn't ignore the `[0/1]` cookie at the end of the "Tasks for today" heading. How can I match the heading when the cookie at the end is variable?

Thanks!